# How to install couchdb version 2.3.0

Tags: couchdb, ubuntu-16.04

I am following [this](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/install/unix.html) guide to install couchDB on Ubuntu 16.04. Everytime I tried, it installs only version 1.6.0. I tried installing and unstalling many time but it is not updating and I am getting only above official guide to install it.

What is the way to install the latest version?

Comment: Did you check, if the CouchDB repository is correctly added in /etc/apt/sources.list? Is it listed with `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: yes i can see it : `deb https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb {xenial} main
`

Comment: remove the `{}`, it should be `xenial` only

Comment: oh. Update it in answer so that i can accept it.

Comment: I added a notice about disitribution selection. I think the answer gives the correct steps to be a solution for the question. We figured the individual typo/mistake out in comments, but i think for anyone browsing to this question, the answer is sufficient and correct to get it installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Ubuntu about the official CouchDB repository:

```
echo "deb https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb xenial main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Be sure to set your distribution correctly, in the above replace `xenial` with what matches your distribution:

- Ubuntu 14.04: `trusty`
- Ubuntu 16.04: `xenial`
- Ubuntu 18.04: `bionic`

You then also need to trust the new repository, by adding its public key to apt:

```
curl -L https://couchdb.apache.org/repo/bintray-pubkey.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then you can install CouchDB with apt:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install couchdb
```

See official CouchDB [install instructions](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/install/unix.html).

Comment: You referred same link as in question. I followed that only.

Comment: Do i need to install `sudo apt install couchdb-bin` too. I can see the repo is 2.3.0. But for running couchDB on terminal i have to install above dependency. On installation, it returns version as 1.6.0

Comment: For normal use, the `couchdb` package is enough. What do you mean with " for running on terminal"? You can start/stop the service with `service`utility, run `sudo service couchdb` for a list of commands.

Comment: `couchdb-bin` is 1.x only (and also `couchdb-common`). You should uninstall any old couchdb installation with `sudo apt-get remove couchdb couchdb-bin couchdb-common -yf`and then reinstall from the newly added repository.

Comment: How to install the specific version of coudb. Here I cannot see any place specifying the version  @Enno